# Back Button Getting Hidden When Show Page Comes Up In A List View

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have the following jQuery mobile code

`<ul data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="b">

                <g:each in="${categoryList}" var="category">

            <li>    <img src="../images/${category.imageName}"/>

               <h3 class="ul-li-heading">${category.name}</h3>

                <ul>

                    <g:if test="${category.userCategories}">

                    <g:each in="${category.userCategories}" var="ads">

                        <li>

                            Category: ${ads.category}

                        </li>

                        <li>

                            User:  ${ads.user?.name}

                        </li>

                        <li>

                            Option: ${ads.optionName}

                        </li>

                        <li>
                            Description: ${ads.description}

                        </li>

                        <hr/>
                    </g:each>

                    </g:if>

                    <g:else>

                        <br/><br/><br/><br/>

                        <li> No User Category Description Added To Show </li>

                    </g:else>

                </ul>

            </li>

        </g:each>

        <div class="paginateButtons">

            <g:paginate total="${categoryInstanceTotal}"/>
        </div>
    </ul>`

The problem is that the code works fine as you see it first renders a list which is actually a thumbnail view and when I click on the thumbnail the show button comes up with other information. But, the problem is the back button which is added automatically wraps up with the content and I am not able to increase the size of the back button div which has the following code autogenerated.

`<div class="ui-bar-b ui-header" data-theme="b" data-role="header" role="banner">`
Its height is 22, if I increase it with firebug it increases, but when I try to apply css, it does not work .
 Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add `!important` to your CSS declarations or you can create a more specific rule than the jQuery Mobile rules (which they make possible on purpose):

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-header {
    height : 100px;
}
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-header a {
    height : 90px;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cAr7w/

`.ui-mobile` refers to the HTML element after jQuery Mobile initializes, `.ui-page` refers to pseudo-page elements, and `.ui-header` refers to the header element within each pseudo-page.